# Javascript this Context in a Callback Method

Tags: javascript, ajax, this

I'm new to Javascript. This code mostly works but something weird happens. When I call `.send()` it fires off the async request and returns normally but the problem is the `this` context when calling the `WebCall.prototype.__stateChangedCallback` method. In Chrome `this` is the XMLHttpRequest object while I'd have thought that it would be the `WebCall` object instead. Can anyone explain to me why this is?

```
function log (message) {
    if(typeof console == "object") {
        console.log(message);
    }
}

function WebCall () {
    var __callMethod;
    this.__callMethod = this.createXmlHttpRequest();
}

WebCall.prototype.createXmlHttpRequest = function () {
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
}

WebCall.prototype.beginGet = function(url) {
    this.__callMethod.open("GET", url, true);
    this.__callMethod.onreadystatechange = this.__stateChangedCallback;
    this.__callMethod.send();
}

WebCall.prototype.__stateChangedCallback = function(readyState, status) {
    // this points to the XMLHttpRequest rather than the WebCall object WHY??!
    var request = this.__callMethod;
    if(request.readyState == 4) {
        if (request.status == 200) {
            this.onRequestCompleted(request);
        } else {
            this.onRequestFailed(status, request);
        }
    }
}

WebCall.prototype.onRequestCompleted = function (request) {

}

WebCall.prototype.onRequestFailed = function(status, request) {
    log("Request failed status= " + status);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scoping problem with Javascript callback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005953/scoping-problem-with-javascript-callback)

Comment: The problem is on this line:
`this.__callMethod.onreadystatechange = this.__stateChangedCallback;` I'll let them who can better explain why do so.

Comment: I figured that much I don't understand why it works like that. What's going on behind the scenes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have in `WebCall.prototype.__stateChangedCallback` is just reference to anonymous function:

```
WebCall.prototype.__stateChangedCallback = function(readyState, status) {
   //......................................^^^^ anonymous function
}
```

This line:

```
this.__callMethod.onreadystatechange = this.__stateChangedCallback;
```

means , that you have another reference to that same anonymous function. This anonymous function is not part of your prototype object.You *just have reference* on it in your prototype object.

Workaround would be this:

```
var that = this;
this.__callMethod.onreadystatechange = function(readyState, status){
    //Calling anonymous function with 'this' context
    WebCall.prototype.__stateChangedCallback.apply( that, arguments );
}
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing to fix it. That's really confusing coming from C# thinking it was equivalent to anonymous functions.

Comment: @JeremyEdwards The search term you'll want to use for future reading is 'javascript closure'.