# Javascript OOP calling object functions (getUserMedia)

Tags: javascript, oop, getusermedia

I have a problem with my javascript code since I started changing it to an OOP approach. I want to create an Object class with many class functions within and the class functions should be able to call each other. But this is not working. Here is a (simpified) code snippet:

```
function MyClass(){
    this.someClassVariable = false;
    this.anotherClassVariable = 10;
}

MyClass.prototype = {
    constructor: MyClass,

   firstFunction:function(){
       if (this.someClassVariable == false){
           this.secondFunction();
       }
   },

   secondFunction:function(){
       while(this.anotherClassVariable != 0){
           this.anotherClassVariable--;
           console.log(this.anotherClassVariable);
       }
   }
}

var myClass = new MyClass();
navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true}, myClass.firstFunction, function(e) {});
```

This always gets me the the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: __tracer.traceFunCall(...) is not a function
```

But when I call the Class and Function without getUserMedia() like this:

```
var myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.firstFunction();
```

it works.
Am I missing something? Would be really glad if someone could give me a hint, searched a lot for this specific topic but didn't find anything.

Thanks!

Comment: What about `myClass.firstFunction.bind(myClass)` ?

Comment: here `myClass.firstFunction` you pass reference to function, so when this would be called - `this` inside would be not referes to `myClass` variable

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scoping problem with Javascript callback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005953/scoping-problem-with-javascript-callback)

Answer (score 0):

Try out

```
navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true}, myClass.firstFunction.bind(myClass), function(e) {});
```

Comment: Please elaborate your code-snippet with some explanation.

Comment: this didn't solve the problem unfortunately, still getting the error message